# How to run qnx executables from Jenkins on Windows platforms?

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, msbuild, qnx

I've been trying to migrate my whole test projects to Jenkins which includes both Windows and Qnx C++ codes. Since I'm trying to manage all the continuous integration from the windows platform, I installed jenkins only on the windows machine.

Inside Jenkins, I created 2 different jobs, one for windows related codes and the other for qnx related codes. For windows related codes, there is no problem on building, running and collecting gtest outputs like passed/failed results or code coverage. (I use Visual Studio with OpenCppCoverage tool, so inside Jenkins, msbuild plugin and some windows shell commands are enough to create results for cobertura and junit plugins)

However, for the qnx related part I have the problem:
(For qnx projects I'm using Qnx Momentics) Inside Jenkins, I checkout the project to the windows machine from subversion, and use "mkbuild" command (which works fine for windows). This builds the project automatically and create the executable on windows. But I could not manage to run the executable (on the target qnx machine) to collect the test results from Jenkins.

I have checked many plugins but couldn't find some to solve this problem.

Is there any option to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @LexLi yes, but cygwin does not let you run the linux executables on windows.

Comment: But why do you want to use Windows in the first place? Linux is free.

Comment: @LexLi I have them both installed on different machines, and the project needs both of them too.

Comment: Due to the complexity of both OS it is common practice to use two machines with each OS. You cannot use a single machine with single OS to achieve this.

Comment: Step 1 - Install jenkins slave on windows host and QNX host. Does QNX runs java?  Java is needed for running jenkins (master or slave)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831000/can-i-use-java-on-qnx

Answer (score 0):

One similar question was asked for hudson, and it was proposed there to use virtual machines and creating slaves for each one.  Using different slaves may solve the problem, I will try this.

[How to use hudson when building for multiple platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511636/how-to-use-hudson-when-building-for-multiple-platforms)